# Deconvolution in Caffe - blob size exceeds INT_MAX

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I have, admittedly, a rather large network. It's based on a network from a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5928) that claims to use Caffe for the implementation. Here's the topology:

[image: Topology of generative deconvolutional neural network]

To the best of my ability, I've tried to recreate the model. The authors use the term "upconv" which is a combination of 2x2 unpooling followed by 5x5 convolution. I've taken this to mean a deconvolutional layer with stride 2 and kernel size 5 (please do correct me if you believe otherwise). Here's a short snippet from the full [model](https://pastebin.com/6pg7DvSC) and [solver](https://pastebin.com/rTuJhX8U):

```
...

# upconv2
layer {
  name: "upconv2"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "upconv1rec"
  top: "upconv2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 65536 # 256x16x16
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "upconv2-rec"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "upconv2"
  top: "upconv2rec"
  relu_param {
    negative_slope: 0.01
  }
}

# upconv3
layer {
  name: "upconv3"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "upconv2rec"
  top: "upconv3"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 94208 # 92x32x32
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 2
  }
}

...
```

But it seems this is too large for Caffe to handle:

```
I0502 10:42:08.859184 13048 net.cpp:86] Creating Layer upconv3
I0502 10:42:08.859184 13048 net.cpp:408] upconv3 <- upconv2rec
I0502 10:42:08.859184 13048 net.cpp:382] upconv3 -> upconv3
F0502 10:42:08.859184 13048 blob.cpp:34] Check failed: shape[i] <= 2147483647 / count_ (94208 vs. 32767) blob size exceeds INT_MAX
```

How can I get around this limitation?

Comment: You are mistaking `num_output` which is the number of kernels. for `upconv2` it is `256` and for `upconv3` it is `92`. Height width are  calculated from `kernel_size` and `stride`.

Comment: @Inman It can't be. If I set `num_output` like that, the size of the output would just be 3, which is incorrect: `euclidean_loss_layer.cpp:12] Check failed: bottom[0]->count(1) == bottom[1]->count(1) (3 vs. 49152) Inputs must have the same dimension.`